# how to compare two fields in a file and print the one that has data using awk?

Tags: bash, awk, solaris

I am using the following comment:

```
   awk -F "\"*_\"*" '{print ";189;" $5||$4 ";-6"}' file.txt
```

The thing is field5 may be empty , so in this case  I want to display what is in field4 , not empty space.

But when performing this comment , the output is truncated at 189;

So how can i print field5 if it has data , and if not print that of field4 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this format instead:

```
awk -F "\"*_\"*" '{print ";189;" ($5 ? $5 : $4) ";-6"}' file.txt
```

Also, do you really need to have two " and * for -F?

Comment: Note that this will fail if $5 has data and that data has a numeric value of zero (e.g. 0 or 0.00 or ...). The test needs to be `($5 == "" ? $4 : $5)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a ternary operator:

```
print ($5 ? $5 : $4)
```

If `$5` is non zero and not an empty string, it will print the contents of `$5`. Otherwise it will print the contents of `$4`

If the fifth field may be zero, then you can use this:

```
print ($5 != "" ? $5 : $4)
```

Comment: If that is the case we should have shown `($5 != "" ? $5 : $4)` to only apply with empty strings.